# Can't access terminal in Manjaro

Tags: desktop, manjaro

I installed Manjaro a few minutes ago and decided to try some of the fonts. I clicked the "Clean" font and the screen started to flash, apparently XFCE crashed and everything turned gray and the UI is gone.

I found some solutions [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-desktop-broke-after-changing-font-to-terminus/13043/16) but first I need access to a terminal before I can try these fixes. I tried "Super-T" and "Control-Alt-T" but I can't get to a terminal.

So I'm looking for some kind of hotkey to access a terminal in Manjaro. I haven't tried rebooting yet.

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Alt+F2` (or any of F1 through F6 probaly)?  From there a `killall Xorg` might get you to your graphical login, or you could troubleshoot some from the console.

Comment: @airhuff I don't think so. I tried Alt-F1, Alt-F2, etc. I tried F1, F2, etc. I didn't try Control-Alt combinations. I was downloading some updates when the problem happened and didn't want to get too aggressive, because I didn't want to abort the installation of the updates. Then I did a full shutdown and the system came back fine. And I promptly returned back to the default font :-) I'm not sure if the system update was the solution, or if it automatically corrected itself after rebooting. In any case, I don't want to reproduce the problem :-)

Comment: You must use `Ctrl+Alt+F1` etc., not just `Alt+F1`.  This will give you a console.  To get back to what there is of the graphical display, you would use `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (this is common, and what is used in Manjaro, but it is distribution-specific).  I'm glad it's resolved anyway!

Answer (score -1):

change in keyboard aplication shortcuts

```
xfce4-terminal --drop-down
```

[image]

if not fun try this

```
sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring manjaro-keyring
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro
sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
```

and aply last configuration